# Windows -MDM autoenrollment with AAD join not able to connect to Terms of use URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD (with AD connect syncing it to local AD).  I added a new On premise mobile management application through AAD-> Mobility(MDM and MAM)-> Add application ->On-premise MDM.

I have configured the terms of url and discovery url to my MDM server and checked that link is reachable and working.

I have assigned Enterprise mobility license to the user.

When I try to join an existing windows 10 device to AAD the terms of use url is not rendered, instead it throws below error.

[image]

If I remove the MDM application the AAD join is successful.

I have checked license and URL access what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nobody can help you with such an error, contact the site owner.

Comment: Hey Asolanki, I'm currently looking into this issue, for you. For future viewers, we are currently discussing the issue on MSDN forums, link is here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/813cbe0f-baf8-481e-a5f3-e44241e7ac97/windows-mdm-autoenrollment-with-aad-join-not-able-to-connect-to-terms-of-use-url?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging we figured the issue was due to app-id uri not being set in the app.
You can set the app-id uri using following 
Navigate to app configuration->Expose an API
The option to set the app-id uri is on top,you can set it as your on-prem application uri.
The msdn documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/registration-config-specific-application-property-how-to?WT.mc_id=UI_AAD_Registered_Apps_Troubleshooting_L2_Overview).